# SMTP not reachable

Tags: postfix, smtp

for some time now I am not able to reach SMTP on port 25 or 587 on a server of mine from the outside though both ports are open and postfix is listening on them:

```
$ telnet domain.tld 25
Telnet escape character is '^]'.
Trying *.*.*.*...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out

$ iptables -S
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN

$ netstat -anpt | grep master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1081/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1081/master
```

Sending mails from the server itself works (through command line & web interface) and fetching mails through IMAP is also possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you talked with your provider? They may be blocking those ports.

Comment: I don't think so. It's a root server with an option to use Plesk including mails. And for my local network I can connect to the same ports on other server so I don't think that some firewall is blocking this of.

Comment: My question stands. Don't make assumptions. Ask them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tcptraceroute mydomain 25
```

will tell you which host is blocking port 25 (compared to mtr or traceroute mydomain)

Comment: Thanks. That helped me. Traceroute for port 25 stopped at my new router. It has some "secure mail server" list integrated and SMTP access is by default only granted for those servers. Deactivating that list helped.